# abnormal exited rosnode still be seen on Master?

Tags: ros, rosnode, ros-kinetic, rosmaster

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, everyone:
I see Master is a xmlRPC server that maintains all the information of all nodes,
but when a node abnormal exited, that node still can be seen on the master ?
How can I check the active status of that node?   Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/285530/abnormal-exited-rosnode-still-be-seen-on-master?/) by [zcm](https://answers.ros.org/users/33932/zcm/) on ROS Answers with karma: 29 on 2018-03-15

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> when a node abnormal exited, that node still can be seen on the master ?

yes.

[rosnode cleanup](http://wiki.ros.org/rosnode#rosnode_cleanup) is a way to try and rectify such a situation, but it's not entirely without faults. See the linked discussion in #q9521.

> How can I check the active status of that node?

I would say the same way `rosnode cleanup` does it: [rosnode_cleanup()](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/blob/94aaaec56e51840d8a39de383c6e89054af97e1e/tools/rosnode/src/rosnode/__init__.py#L454-L477). It essentially "pings" (xmlrpc) all nodes it knows about and any node that did not respond are considered dead, and deregistered.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-03-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-03-15**:
Btw: the various `rosnode`, `rostopic` and `rosservice` Python tools (and libraries) provide a lot of this functionality. Seeing your previous question (#q285515), I would first check those whenever you want to interact with the ROS node graph.

**Comment by [zcm](https://answers.ros.org/users/33932/zcm/) on 2018-03-15**:
Thanks! Very good explanation! I will check these documents.